# casperjs (phantomjs) unable to submit form after website update

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, phantomjs

I've had a script running for a while until recently after a website update.

https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/buy-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry

What I was doing was filling a form, clicking submit and scraping the results.

Now it seems no matter what I do, click, send an enter key.. etc the form won't submit.

I have the following debug lines from casper:

```
casperjs casper1.js
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 4 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/buy-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/buy-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/buy-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/4 https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/buy-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/4: done in 1579ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/5 https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/buy-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/5: done in 1599ms.
[info] [phantom] waitFor() finished in 40ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 4/5 https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/buy-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry (HTTP 200)
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mousedown' on selector: form#form1
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mouseup' on selector: form#form1
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: form#form1
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 4/5: done in 1691ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 5/5 https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/buy-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry (HTTP 200)
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to /var/www/html/poc/phantom/test.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to /var/www/html/poc/phantom/test.png
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 5/5: done in 1964ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 5 steps in 1967ms
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to /var/www/html/poc/phantom/test0.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to /var/www/html/poc/phantom/test0.png
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "about:blank"
```

---

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36',
    XSSAuditingEnabled: false,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    javascriptEnabled:'false',
    viewportSize: {
            width: 1280,
        height: 720
    },
    pageSettings: {
        ignoreSslErrors: true,
        loadImages: false, // do not load images
        loadPlugins: false, // do not load NPAPI plugins (Flash, Silverlight, ...)
        webSecurityEnabled: false,
        localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: false
    }
});

casper.start('https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/buy-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry', function() {
   // Wait for the form
   this.waitForSelector('form#form1');
});

casper.then(function() {
   // fill the form
   this.fill('form#form1', { "ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_0$panel$VehicleSearch$RegistrationNumberCar$RegistrationNumber_CtrlHolderDivShown": "ZJD402" }, false);
   this.click('form#form1');
});

casper.then(function() {
        this.capture('test.png');
});

casper.run(function() {
    // dump
    this.capture('test0.png');
    //this.debugPage();
    this.exit();
});
```

---

I have also tried waiting for the selector containing the results, but it never arrives.

Any phantomjs / casperjs gurus have any tricks up their sleeves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not clicking the submit button, but the entire form.

```
this.click('form#form1');
```

A formulary is not a button, so is not "clickable". You should look for the submit button and click it. In this case I do it right this:

```
this.click('"#main input[type='submit']"');
```

And that's it.

With the `'form#form1'` thinghy you were actually looking for `submit`, but I don't think that calling `submit` directly on the form will trigger the `onClick` events that are attached to the button, so if you want to simulate user actions 100%, is better to click the button than directly submitting a form.

To submit a form directly, just remove the `false` attribute at the end of the `fill` method.

Comment: thanks for your time, will give this a go.
my other thought was using a javascript disabled version of phantomjs.

Comment: @vivvvi Woah, a "low-points" user saying "thank you for your time". That's difficult nowadays here xD I appreciate it.

Comment: As the waitfor('element') wasn't working, I don't think a wait is going to make any difference.

My other thought was eliminating such events that may be bound by disabling javascript in the headless browser.

Comment: `waitFor("element")` do nothing. `waitFor` is to accept a function that will run custom checks. With the `waitFor...` (note the dots) methods I was talking is all the `waitForUrl`, `waitForResource`, etc... or inclusive the `waitFor()` with your own function, but you have to be creative. For example, add an event listener that will be called each time the url is changed and also call call `waitFor` with a function that will check if the url was loaded. Is not a single-line-fix btw.

Comment: Also, as you say, you can try to disable JS, but some websites do not work properly. Try to disable it in your browser and check if it loads. WIll be a faster and less resource consuming solution if it works.

Comment: thanks again.. Site works fine without Javascript.

re the waitFor, I guess I was more referring to .waitForSelector('<element>'); never being fulfilled.

Comment: Unfortunately I have had no luck waiting, and no luck disabling javascript on the page yet.

Comment: I noticed there is a script in base64 format, injected after the page loads. 

(function() {
 var noopfn = function() {
 };
 var w = window;
 w.ga = w.ga || noopfn;
 var dl = w.dataLayer;
 if ( dl instanceof Object === false ) { return; }
 if ( dl.hide instanceof Object && typeof dl.hide.end === 'function' ) {
  dl.hide.end();
 }
 if ( typeof dl.push === 'function' ) {
  dl.push = function(o) {
   if (
    o instanceof Object &&
    typeof o.eventCallback === 'function'
   ) {
    setTimeout(o.eventCallback, 1);
   }
  };
 }
})();

not sure if its relevant.

Comment: @vivvvi Oh, `waitForSelector`. Is not that bad. When you send the form, you expect a message on the page, right? That means that a selector must appear. I've tested it with an error message (I don't know any number to get a valid message) and the problem is that the error messages already exists on the page, but are hidden, so we have to check if any message is shown. Check this: http://i.imgur.com/e4TvMct.png

Comment: This code will wait until an error message is shown and also you can add your own code, following the same pattern, that will set `ok` to true when the correct elements are shown. Is simply that when you click the submit button, it will wait for an ok or error message. When one of them is received, means that the page was loaded.

Comment: Thanks again Jorge.
ZJD402 is a valid registration number.
I'll see if I can make further progress with your advice, however I couldn't even get a screenshot of the page after the submit.

Comment: this.waitForSelector('#main > div > div.detail-module > h2');

I'm expecting to see this appear in the results but I get casper reporting "Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting."

Comment: Ohhh sh*it, I saw the problem. You are not clicking the submit button! haha. Sorry for the whole thingy, but well, I hope you learn a bit more of casperjs with this xD I assumed that the selector on the `click()` method was fine. Going to edit my answer. Check it.

Comment: Thanks Jorge! 
how stupid of me!!

I don't know why I missed this, in multiple iterations of the script.
I've been banging my head thinging they had employed some crazy JS event listeners (like you mentioned).

Glad I didn't let my other work hold me up... Answer Accepted! Congratulations.

THANKYOU!!

Comment: @vivvvi haha, np!